# ggplot: Visualizing two continuous variables in relation to one discrete variable in a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really can't wrap my head around ggplot. My task is to visualize the means of `cty` and `hwy` as functions of `class` in the `mpg` dataset. Geom_bar appeared to be the obvious choice, but after chewing through any resources I could find, I'm not closer to making it work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data("mpg")
ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=class, y=cty, fill=hwy)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun="mean", position=position_dodge())
```

Above is the closest I got, but `hwy` still wouldn't be displayed, despite my efforts. From the many examples I saw, I gathered that `fill` would somehow result in more columns.

Is there any collected manual for stuff like this, with all the settings and subfunctions and modes explained in detail? The inbuilt help function for example didn't tell me about the many settings of the `stat` argument, which is quite vital.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Stack's tag-recommendation system is imperfect, when it recommends tags please verify that they are appropriate. In this case, mouse-over (or click on) the [tag:rstudio] tag and note that it says *"DO NOT use this tag for general R programming questions ... ONLY use for RStudio-specific questions"*. The basic test is that if your problem behaves differently in the basic R interpreter (`R`, `R.exe`, or `Rgui`, not within the RStudio IDE), then the [tag:rstudio] tag might be relevant, otherwise _it is not_.

Comment: Similarly, [tag:tidyverse] says *"DO NOT USE if your question relates to one or two components"*, and this question seems to be solely about `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for new users to try and get `ggplot2` to work for their data. Instead, it is most often better to get your data to work for `ggplot2`. By this I mean it is easier to get you dataset into a form that `ggplot2` likes. Here, the `tidyverse` packages `dplyr` and `tidyr` are your friend. In the following, data are first converted to long format and mean values are then calculated for each subgroup (cty, hwy) of group "class":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data("mpg")

# Transform data for plotting
df <- mpg %>% select(class, cty, hwy) %>% # Subset the columns you need
  pivot_longer(cols = c(cty, hwy), # Pivot "cty" and "hwy" values into one column
               names_to = "type",
               values_to = "mpgvar") %>%
  group_by(class, type) %>% # Group by "class" and subgroups in "type"  
  summarise(mean = mean(mpgvar), .groups = "drop") # Calculate mean by previously defined groups

# Plot result
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = class, y = mean, fill = type)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: You don't need to use `geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")` if the data was already summarised using `summarise`. Just `geom_col(position = position_dodge())` should work in that case. Or you could pipe the output of `pivot_longer` straight to `ggplot()` if you want to use the `geom_bar()` syntax.

Comment: @neilfws - Thanks for that, answer updated accordingly.